# Primefaces Chart zoom and theme behaviour

Tags: jsf, charts, primefaces

I wanted to try out the primefaces library for jsf and see if it fits my needs in regards to dashboarding and chart creation. I tried setting up a dashboard with some fake data in a linechart to evaluate how it behaves:

```
<div style="height:500px">
                <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
                <p:dashboard id="board" model="#{dashboardManagedBean.model}">
                    <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{dashboardManagedBean.handleReorder}" update="msgs" />
                    <p:panel width="100%" id="Finance" header="Finance" closable="true" toggleable="true">
                        <p:chart type="line" model="#{dashboardManagedBean.chartModel}" style="height:500px;"/>

                    </p:panel>
                </p:dashboard>
        </div>
```

This is the dashboard bean:

```
package com.journaldev.primefaces.beans;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.DashboardReorderEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DashboardColumn;
import org.primefaces.model.DashboardModel;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultDashboardColumn;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultDashboardModel;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.*;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DashboardManagedBean {
    private DashboardModel model;
    private LineChartModel chartModel;
    public DashboardManagedBean() {
        // Initialize the dashboard model
        this.model = new DefaultDashboardModel();
        DashboardColumn column2 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();
        column2.addWidget("Finance");
        this.model.addColumn(column2);
        chartModel = new LineChartModel();
        chartModel.setTitle("Linear Chart");
        chartModel.setLegendPosition("e");
        chartModel.setZoom(true);

        LineChartSeries series1 = new LineChartSeries();
        series1.setLabel("Series 1");
        chartModel.addSeries(series1);
        Date date = new Date();
        double y = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            series1.set(date.getTime() +  1000*i,y);
            y+=Math.random();
        }

        DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Dates");
        axis.setTickAngle(-50);
        axis.setTickFormat("%d.%m.%y %H:%#M:%S");
        axis.setMin("09.09.18 17:38:00");
        axis.setMax("09.09.18 18:00:00");
        axis.setTickCount(12);
        chartModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);



    }

    public DashboardModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public LineChartModel getChartModel() {
        return chartModel;
    }

    public void setModel(DashboardModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

}
```

And the result I got looks mostly good. The issues start coming in when I try zooming in the chart, then it gets really scuffed:
[Zoomed Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2dDI.png)

So i have multiple concerns regarding primefaces charts:

- Why is the theme I picked not applied? I installed the maven dependencies and added to the web.xml. For the rest of the dashboard it seems to work out.
- Why does the zooming behave this weirdly?
- Is there really no autoscaling on the linechart available for xmin and xmax?

Thanks for helping an absolute primefaces noob.

Comment: Try this Showcase: PrimeFaces is rewriting all of their charts to use ChartsJS from the old Jquery Chart library they were using which had problems with Zooming and scaling. They just released it in PrimeFaces 6.2.9 or you can build 6.3-SNAPSHOT from GitHub Source.  Check it out: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartjs/line.xhtml

Comment: This looks like this could work but I can not find 6.2.9 on the maven repository

Comment: 6.2.9 is for Elite subscribers only.  If you want to test this out you will have to build 6.3-SNAPSHOT from the GitHub source code.

Comment: What is usually the release cycle for non elite people of primefaces?

Comment: About every 6-9 months they do a major release. So 6.3 is most likely around December.